# SSRS - A Subtotal of every row previously, regardless of group

Tags: reporting-services

As the title says, I have a tablix which shows data returned from a SP; the tablix contains groups with their own totals which work fine, however in the data returned I have a column with a subtotal flag which is supposed to indicate that I need to supply a subtotal of all the previous amounts, regardless if they share the same group.

So what I've done so far is to:

1. Create a row which is hidden unless the column flag is true
2. Created a variable which has the sum total of the column

currently 2. returns the grand total for the entire dataset returned, so I somehow need to subtract everything after that flag, or I need to find a better way to return the SUM of column before it.

any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: would be easier to do this in SQL if that is where the data is coming from.. using a  sum over and a partition by ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create custom calculations with code.

Add the following code to your report

```
Public Dim flag As Integer
Public Dim sum1 As Decimal

Public Function CustomSum(ByVal num1 As Decimal, current_flag As Integer) As Decimal

If current_flag =1 Then flag = 1

If flag = 0 Then sum1 = sum1 + num1

Return num1

End Function
```

The code creates a cumulative sum value until it finds flag = 1.

Set your value expression to `= Code.CustomSum(Fields!val.Value, Fields!flag1.Value)`

Set your custom sum expression to `=Code.sum1`

Below there is a sample report. On the gray color part of the tablix I have used the expressions.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks niktrs :), didn't realise you could create custom functions within SSRS. I Also appreciate the work put into your answer.

Comment: You are welcome. You can use custom code (vb) or dll files (any .net language) to extend functionallity in your reports.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-design/add-code-to-a-report-ssrs?view=sql-server-ver15